# Find all ordered combinations of filtered elements using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, combinatorics

I want to find all ordered combinations of strings filtered only to include those with a particular string present, given the following structure:

```
//elements
string[] a = { "a1" };
string[] b = { "b1", "b2", "b3" };
string[] c = { "c1", "c2" };

//element groups
string[][] m = { a, b };
string[][] n = { a, b, c };
string[][] o = { b };
string[][] p = { b, c };

//element group groupings
string[][][] groupGroupings = { m, n, o, p };
```

Given groupGroupings, and filtered to only include combinations where, let's say "b2" is present, the output should be the following:

```
["a1", "b2"]
["a1", "b2", "c1"]
["a1", "b2", "c2"]
["b2"]
["b2", "c1"]
["b2", "c2"]
```

I have a recursive approach that works, but it's a bit ugly and I can't help feeling like there is a more elegant approach to this.

I'm interested in how something like this might be done using just LINQ, not sure if that's possible, but I'm not seeing it yet.

My current approach:

```
List<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>> all = new List<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>>();
foreach (var groups in groupGroupings)
{
    var combos = FindAllCombinations(groups).Where(i => i.Any(g => g.Contains("b2"))).ToList();
    all.Add(combos);
}

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> FindAllCombinations(string[][] groups)
{
    if (groups.Length > 0)
    {
        var group = groups.First();
        var remainingGroups = groups.SkipWhile(g => !g.Equals(group)).Skip(1);
        var remainingCombinations = FindAllCombinations(remainingGroups.ToArray()).ToList();

        foreach (var element in group)
        {
            if (remainingGroups.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var c in remainingCombinations)
                {
                    List<string> combo = new List<string>() { element };
                    combo.AddRange(c);
                    yield return combo;
                }
            }
            else
                yield return new List<string>() { element };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't like the recursive solution. I think it's a good one. However, I think there are couple improvements that could be done.

1. Call `ToArray()` when creating `remainingGroups` variable. Otherwise it will be `IEnumerable<T>` defined using `SkipWhile`/`Skip` and every time `.Count()` is called it will have to be evaluated again and again and entire collection will be enumerated. With an array you can use `Length` instead.
2. I don't understand why you use `SkipWhile` at all. `group` will always be the first element, so `SkipWhile(g => !g.Equals(group))` will never skip anything. I think you can just use `Skip(1)` and omit `SkipWhile`.
3. You can define `elementList = new List<string>() { element }` at the very beginning of outer `foreach` loop and use it to easily `yield return` values from inner loop using `Concat()`/`ToList()` methods chain.

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> FindAllCombinations(string[][] groups)
{
    if (groups.Length == 0)
        yield break;

    var group = groups.First();
    var remainingGroups = groups.Skip(1).ToArray();
    var remainingCombinations = FindAllCombinations(remainingGroups).ToList();

    foreach (var element in group)
    {
        var elementList = new List<string>() { element };

        if (remainingGroups.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var c in remainingCombinations)
            {
                yield return elementList.Concat(c).ToList();
            }
        }
        else
            yield return elementList;
    }
}
```

You can also change your `foreach` to `Select` method:

```
var all = groupGroupings.Select(g => FindAllCombinations(g).Where(i => i.Any(j => j.Contains("b2"))).ToList()).ToList();
```

**Update**

If you really want to use LINQ, you can use Cartesian Product method described by Eric Lippert on his blog: [Computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
      emptyProduct,
      (accumulator, sequence) =>
        from accseq in accumulator
        from item in sequence
        select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
}
```